# restfb purchase content-ids

Tags: api, graph, explorer, restfb

I am new to RestFB.
I am trying to get information on how to get data from purchases (and related content-ids), tracked by the following code, but with no success.

```
<script>
! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
    if (f.fbq) return;
    n = f.fbq = function() {
        n.callMethod ?
            n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
    };
    if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
    n.push = n;
    n.loaded = !0;
    n.version = '2.0';
    n.queue = [];
    t = b.createElement(e);
    t.async = !0;
    t.src = v;
    s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
}(window,
    document, 'script', '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
// Insert Your Custom Audience Pixel ID below. 
fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX');
// Replace the values for the parameters below with actual values of the purchase
fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
    content_name: '',
    content_category: '',
    content_ids: ['4363319'],
    content_type: 'product',
    value: 1.0,
    currency: 'EUR'
});
```

I have looked also in "Graph API Explorer", but I could not find this kind of info.

Can anyone help me out with this, please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please de-obsfucate the code of your js function, because it is hard to read as it is.

Comment: @PlamenPetrov  De-obfuscated.